# How can i make this factorial function recursive?

Tags: python, recursion

A function that calculates (n-1)! , but with steps.

```
def function1(n, step):
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, n, step):
        result *= i

    return result
```

I'm not allowed to add any more parameters and I need to make it recursive.
I've tried this:

```
def function2(n, step):
    if n < 0:
        return 1

    return n * function2(n-step, step)
```

But for let's say:

```
function2(6,3)
```

it wouldn't work, the first function will give me `1 * 4`
and the second one would give me `6 * 3 * 1`

I don't know how to make it work with the step argument.

Edit:
Some more samples:

```
First function
function1(13, 3) == 280
function1(11, 3) == 280
function1(6, 3) == 4
function1(11, 2) == 945
function1(8, 2) == 105
function1(4, 2) == 3
More sample: 
function1(12, 3) == 280
function1(5, 2) == 3
function1(5, 3) == 4

Second function (same values):
function2(13, 3) == 3640
function2(11, 3) == 880
function2(6, 3) == 0
function2(11, 2) == 10395
function2(8, 2) == 0
function2(4, 2) == 0
```

Edit2: Some more clarifications: The function computes (n-1)!, but with steps. The step argument would just "step over" or "skip" some numbers (e.g.: `function1(12, 3)` should compute `1*4*7*10`, like with the step argument from range(), cause it's used in the first function)

Thank you!

Comment: What is the point of the step argument? What are the expected results of  function2(5, 2) vs function2(5, 3)?

Comment: I added 5,2 and 5,3 to function1() in the input/output sample. The point of step argument is that, if we have function1(5, 1), it would compute: 1*2*3*4, that would be (n-1)!. but with (5,2), it should compute 1*3 (without 5, cause it's (n-1)!, cause in the first function, range it's used, and that goes up to n-1)

Comment: the obvious difference is that you are building `range` starting at 1 and counting **up** to `n` by `step`, and in the recursive example you are starting at `n` and counting **down** by `step`. this will result in different numbers being multiplied

Comment: Yes, that's the main problem, I don't actually know how to make it so that I can start from 1 and go up to n-1, I cannot define any more parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious difference is that you are building `range` starting at 1 and counting **up** to `n` by `step`, and in the recursive example you are starting at `n` and counting **down** by `step`. This will result in different numbers being multiplied.

Because you are required not to use any additional function parameters, I would suggest an inner helper function, `loop` -

```py
def fact (n, step):
  def loop (m):
    if m >= n:
      return 1
    else:
      return m * loop(m + step)
  return loop(1)
```

If you don't want to use a helper function like `loop` above, you are constrained to complex modulus arithmetic -

```py
def fact (n, step):
  if n % step != 1:
    return fact(n + 1, step)
  elif n < step:
    return 1
  else:
    return (n - step) * fact(n - step, step)
```

No matter which way you shake it, the modulus operation for this problem is messy -

```py
def fact (n, step):
  q = (n - 1) % step
  if q:
    return fact(n + step - q, step)
  elif n < step:
    return 1
  else:
    return (n - step) * fact(n - step, step)
```

Once academic constraints like *"do not use additional parameters"* go away, you can multiply the ascending series in a more familiar way -

```py
def fact (n, step, m = 1):
  if m >= n:
    return 1
  else:
    return m * fact(n, step, m + step)
```

All variations of `fact` above produce identical output -

```py
print(fact(13, 3) == 280) # True
print(fact(11, 3) == 280) # True
print(fact(6, 3) == 4) # True
print(fact(11, 2) == 945) # True
print(fact(8, 2) == 105) # True
print(fact(4, 2) == 3) # True
print(fact(5, 2) == 3) # True
print(fact(5, 3) == 4) # True
```

Comment: This is really clever, but I find it too much of an advanced technique for this type of exercise. Thank you!

Comment: @yierstem i added some additional solutions. you should not see using a helper function as _really clever_ or _too advanced_. this is a common practice in all programming languages.

Comment: No, I didn't mean to say that I'm too scared of them, it's just that we haven't learned about closures or nested functions yet, so it wouldn't make sense for me to use them yet. The arithmetic solution is exactly what I needed, I tried to do it, but I just didn't think about the second if. Thank you again, that's what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Because the steps is calculated beginnig with 1 You have to normalize n to be a multiple of step plus 1 before you begin
And you can cheat the number of arguments by setting the steps negative on recursive calls.

```
def function2(n, step):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    if step > 0: 
        n = n - 2
        n = n - n % step + 1
        step = -step
    return n * function2(n + step, step)
```

Comment: That's what I tried in the end, but I need to somehow make it so I don't have to receive the n parameter differently than it already is (I mean with a different value).

Comment: @yierstem Yes, didn't work. Fixed now. Needed to somewhat cheat on the argument rule

Comment: after edit: that's what I was trying to do for 1 hour now, it is kind of funny 'cause we have to cheat this way, but it does work in the end. As a funny fact, this should've been a 3 minutes exercise (but apparently is unnecessarily complicated). Thanks!